# Sinatra: NoMethodError undefined method `slim'

Tags: ruby, sinatra

What am I missing? I've included slim in my Gemfile & 'required' it.

config.ru:

```
require './sinatra.rb'
run Sinatra::Application
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rack'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'slim'
```

sinatra.rb:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'slim'

get '/' do
  slim :index
end
```

Comment: I've tried that. I'm running it via `rackup config.ru` if that makes a difference.

Comment: Try `gem install slim`. Really strange, i just created this 3 files and it works without any `bundle`

Comment: The only way I can see this happening is if you are using a very old version of Sinatra. What version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for all the help.. I've managed to solve the problem. This worked when I deleted my `vendor` file & the Gemfile.lock. Perhaps I should have run `bundle update` or had some corrupted files..